# Acquiring row level locks in a order

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-deadlocks

I have a table where I am updating multiple rows inside a transaction.

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS s CASCADE;  

CREATE SCHEMA s;
CREATE TABLE s.t1 (
    "id1" Bigint,
    "id2" Bigint,
    CONSTRAINT "pk1" PRIMARY KEY (id1)
)   
WITH(OIDS=FALSE);

INSERT INTO s.t1( id1, id2 )
SELECT x, x * 100 
FROM generate_series( 1,10 ) x;

END TRANSACTION;
```

---

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT id1 FROM s.t1 WHERE id1 > 3 and id1 < 6 ORDER BY id1 FOR UPDATE; /* row lock */
```

I am assuming this will take row level locks in order (id1).
Is my assumption correct ?

So that I will be able to run multiple transactions without ever worrying about deadlocks due to the order of locks on rows.

```
END TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT id1,id2 FROM s.t1 order by id1;

DROP SCHEMA s CASCADE;
```

I did a explain.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id1 FROM s.t1 WHERE id1 > 3 and id1 < 6 ORDER BY id1 FOR  UPDATE;
                              QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 LockRows  (cost=15.05..15.16 rows=9 width=14)
   ->  Sort  (cost=15.05..15.07 rows=9 width=14)
     Sort Key: id1
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t1  (cost=4.34..14.91 rows=9 width=14)
           Recheck Cond: ((id1 > 3) AND (id1 < 6))
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pk1  (cost=0.00..4.34 rows=9 width=0)
                 Index Cond: ((id1 > 3) AND (id1 < 6))
(7 rows)
```

---

Answer: This is correct.

Thanks

Comment: This is either MySQL or Postgres, but it's definitely not both. Can you fix your tags to point to the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Sorry. I have update. It is postgresql.

Comment: You are correct, locking is always done after sorting: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2382.1170171581%40sss.pgh.pa.us